# Configuring instances in Unity Container configured in App.Config at runtime

Tags: c#, configuration, unity-container, system.configuration, configsection

I have a speciifc configuration problem.

```
     <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="custom" type="ConfigurationSample.CustomConfigurationSection, ConfigurationSample"/>
<section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
      </configSections>
        <custom>
       <customConfigurations>
        <configuration id="CAT1">
          <name>Tom</name>
           <address type="rent">
             <area>Misissipi</area>
           </address>
         <conifugration/>
       <configuration id="Mouse1">
         <name>Jerry</name>
           <address type="own">
             <area>Seatle</area>
           </address>
         <conifugration/>
       <customConfigurations>
      </custom>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="IAnimal" type="MyApp.IAnimal, MyApp" />
    <alias alias="CAT" type="MyApp.CAT, MyApp" />
    <alias alias="Mouse" type="MyApp.Mouse, MyApp" />
    <container>
      <!-- should register CAT instance with name CAT1 at runtime and mapto IAnimal !-->    
      <!-- should register Mouse with name Mouse1 at runtime and mapto IAnimal !-->  
    </container>

  </unity>
    </configuration>
```

This is my app.config. All I am looking for runtime registering instances in unity container while reading the custom config section since CAT class CAT configuration in its constructor.

My classes:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
public string Name {get;set}
pubic bool IsLiving();
}


public class Mouse
{
MouseConfig config;
public Mouse(IAnimalConfig config)
{
this.config=config;
}
public string Name {get;set}
pubic bool IsLiving(){
//do something with config
}
}

public class Cat
{
CATConfig config;
public CAT(IAnimalConfig config)
{
this.config=config;
}
public string Name {get;set}
pubic bool IsLiving(){
//do something with config
}
}
```

I hope you understand where i am leading to. I need to provide config objects as parameter to the derived classes. So based on my customconfig i want to register instances in unity container. So i can work with those instances in my application. since i already know their types and name of those instances i can resolve from container.

Please let me know if i have to add anything more. Thanks

Comment: Can you please highlight your container mappings? I don't see where is IAnimalConfig getting registered.

Comment: I don't want to register them in configuration. I want to do them at runtime.